# How to use HiPAM authorization with OpenSSH?

Tags: ssh, openssh, kerberos, hitachi

My client is implementing HiPAM (or [Hitachi ID](https://www.hitachi-id.com/)) for production systems.

One requests temporary access to machines in a certain group, and can, upon approval, access them either via an ssh-client inside the browser, or by launching PuTTY from the browser.

This (kind of) works for interactive access to individual systems, which is the only use-case the people in charge have considered.

However, I need to be able to access dozens of machines via Ansible -- which means, my OpenSSH client needs to be able to use whatever credentials HiPAM issues.

How would I do that? I *suspect* -- but am not sure -- that Hitachi are using Kerberos in some way, but cannot figure out, which way it is...

Comment: [You are going to have to tell us if you are using Kerberos with Hitachi](https://knowledge.hitachivantara.com/Documents/Management_Software/Ops_Center/10.6.x/Analyzer/10.2.x/Configure_external_user_authentication/05_Configuring_Kerberos_authentication_for_Analyzer_server) cause that isn't the only option.  Why don't you just configure your workflow so only after the Ansible configure the machine is configured for HiPAM?  Please [edit] your question with the required information necessary to answer your question.

Comment: I noticed the link is for a slightly different system i suspect that Hitachi ID also supports LDAP

Comment: Configuration of the remote systems is not up to me. I just need to learn, how to use them... Yes, the company is using Kerberos -- and for non-production systems, I can `kinit` and then ssh into the machines, where I've added myself to `~/.k5login`.